# Solr - Join Query return array of values of a field

Tags: solr, multivalue

I am trying to get array of values of a field based on a join query , but return all the values from the second table . And my expected result is

```
{"description":"",
   "id":479,        
   "brand":"Lowepro",
   "mrp":4900,
   "name":"Lowepro Photo Hatchback 16L AW  Camera Bag",
  "brandID":19,         
  "srp":[3773,3547,3685],
  "category":"Camera bags"}
```

Now the result is : all the srp values from the second table(contain srp values).

can You please help me....?Thanks in advance.
Data-config.xml is

```
<entity name="master_products" pk="id"
  query="select p.* ,b.* ,c.*,d.* from master_products p ,master_brands   b,master_product_categories c,master_affiliate_product_mappings d  where b.id=p.brand_id and c.id=p.product_category_id and d.our_product_id=p.id"
deltaImportQuery="SELECT * FROM master_products WHERE product_name='${dataimporter.delta.product_name}' ">
          <field column="product_name" name="name"/>
          <field column="product_description" name="description"/>
          <field column="id" name="id"/>
          <field column="mrp" name="mrp"/>
          <field column="brand_id" name="brandID"/>
          <entity name="master_affiliate_product_mappings"
         query="select * from master_affiliate_product_mappings"
            deltaImportQuery="select * from master_affiliate_product_mappings where our_product_id={master_products.id}"
         processor="SqlEntityProcessor" cacheImpl="SortedMapBackedCache" >
            <field column="srp" name="srp" />
          </entity>

         <entity name="master_brands"
        query="select * from master_brands"
            deltaImportQuery="select * from master_brands where id ={master_products.brand_id}"
         processor="SqlEntityProcessor" cacheImpl="SortedMapBackedCache" >
            <field column="brand" name="brand" />
         </entity>

         <entity name="master_product_categories"
            query="select * from master_product_categories"
            deltaImportQuery="select * from master_product_categories where id ={master_products. product_category_id}"  processor="SqlEntityProcessor" cacheImpl="SortedMapBackedCache" >
          <field column="category" name="category" />
         </entity>
     </entity>
```

Comment: You can't retrieve data from both cores when doing a join in Solr (if that's what you're trying to do) just the destination core. `Limitations: Fields or other properties of the documents being joined "from" are not available for use in processing of the resulting set of "to" documents (ie: you can not return fields in the "from" documents as if they were a multivalued field on the "to" documents)`

Comment: Actually i have only one core, contain multiple entity in data-config.xml.
database table2 ( master_affiliate_product_mappings) contain some mapping values of table 1(master_products). In some cases table2 contain 3 or 4 values of table 1 for some ids , that cases  i need to return the values of particular field only. But now it returns all the values of that field (if  it is 1000 number of rows, return all 1000 rows ). That is my issue.